# Authenticating selective spring web serrvices using wss4j SimplePasswordValidationCallbackHandler

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-ws

I have created and authenticated a sample web service using wss4j SimplePasswordValidationCallbackHandler.

**Endpoint class:**

```
   @Endpoint                                                                               
public class HolidayEndpoint {

  private static final String NAMESPACE_URI = "http://mycompany.com/hr/schemas";

  @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "HolidayRequest") 
  public HolidayResponse handleHolidayRequest(HolidayRequest holidayRequest)              
      throws Exception {
      HolidayResponse result = new HolidayResponse();
    result.setResult(1);
    return result;
  }
}
```

**Configuration:**

```
<bean
        class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping">
        <property name="interceptors">
            <list>
                <ref local="wsServerSecurityInterceptor" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="wsServerSecurityInterceptor"
        class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j.Wss4jSecurityInterceptor">
        <property name="validationActions" value="UsernameToken" />
        <property name="validationCallbackHandler">
            <bean id="callbackHandler"
                class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j.callback.SimplePasswordValidationCallbackHandler">
                <property name="users">
                    <props>
                        <prop key="Bert">Ernie</prop>
                    </props>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

The service and authentication is working fine as such.

Now I want to add another Spring web service which does not have this authentication.
The problem here is that I have not defined anywhere the set of services on which the authentication will be applicable. Hence, for every new spring web service I create, the same authentication rule is applied.

Can anyone please suggest how can I make this authentication applicable only to a select set of services and apply some different authentication rules to different set of services.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to use a `SmartEndpointInterceptor` wrapper for your security interceptor. Smart interceptors have a way to decide whether it should intercept a given message. The easiest way to configure it is in a `<sws:interceptors>` block in your configuration:

```xml
    <sws:annotation-driven/> <!-- Instead of the PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping bean  definition -->

    <sws:interceptors>
        <sws:payloadRoot namespaceUri="http://mycompany.com/hr/schemas" localPart="HolidayRequest">
            <ref bean="wsServerSecurityInterceptor"/>
        </sws:payloadRoot>
    </sws:interceptors>

    <bean id="wsServerSecurityInterceptor"
        class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j.Wss4jSecurityInterceptor">
        <property name="validationActions" value="UsernameToken" />
        <property name="validationCallbackHandler">
            <bean id="callbackHandler"
                class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j.callback.SimplePasswordValidationCallbackHandler">
                <property name="users">
                    <props>
                        <prop key="Bert">Ernie</prop>
                    </props>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

In this example, the security interceptor would only apply for messages with the `http://mycompany.com/hr/schemas` namespace and `HolidayRequest` local name.